# Is there a way i can place tkinter buttons next to each other using .pack() while keeping them center justified?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to have two Tkinter buttons (ttk.Button) next to each other under my entry widgets, while still keeping them centre justified. I am already using .pack() for the other widgets in the frame, so I cannot use .grid() or .place() on them. I know that you can use tk.LEFT, tk.RIGHT and so on to place them in a line, but that moves them to the far edge. Is there a way I can use a method like this to place them next to each other in the centre of the window?

this is my code:

```
class EmailPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        send_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Send Email\'s', command=lambda: send_email())
        send_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        test_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Test Email', command=lambda: test_email())
        test_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your code, so that we can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `tk.Frame` and then pack the buttons in them:

```
from tkinter import ttk   
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root,text='These 2 buttons are in centre!').pack()

f1=tk.Frame(root)
f1.pack(expand=1)
b1=ttk.Button(f1,text='Button 1')
b1.pack(expand=True,side=tk.BOTTOM)
b2=ttk.Button(f1,text='Button 2')
b2.pack(expand=True,side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me. I am using classes to create multiple Tkinter pages, and the classes are used as the root window, I think. When creating the widget, I have to use 'self' in the options, rather than 'f1' as would be necessary for your solution. Please see the code I added to my question earlier to see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I managed to make this work by using tk.LEFT, rather than tk.BOTTOM in my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and appended some necessary methods to make it a working example.

In your example, your button commands do not need `lambda` since you are not sending data to those methods.

Also, `self.` needs to be prepended to widgets and `tk.Frame` needs to be managed.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class EmailPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        entry = tk.Entry( self, width = 40 )
        entry.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = False)

        self.send_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Send Email\'s', command = self.send_email)
        self.send_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.test_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Test Email', command = self.test_email)
        self.test_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

    def send_email( self ):
        pass

    def test_email( self ):
        pass

my_emailer = EmailPage(tk.Tk(), "")
my_emailer.master.mainloop()
```